# Slow Cooked Pork Tenderloin

Tags: slow-cooking

I am using a recipe for pork tenderloin that calls for 2 pounds of meat cooked for 1-2 hours in a slow cooker to 145 degrees.  I want to increase the amount of meat in the slow cooker to 6 pounds of pork tenderloin.  How do I estimate how long to cook for?  I can keep checking the internal temperature, but I'd like to have some sort of reasonable estimate.

Comment: I've always thought that slow cooking is better suited for cuts of meat that are well-marbled and have connective tissue that breaks down for a richer-tasting final dish - like a shoulder or butt roast. A tenderloin would seem to be the opposite of that and more suited for some other technique. Have you tried this one before? Not meant as criticism or telling you to do otherwise, just wondering how the results turn out.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet slow cooking approaches can work well for lean cuts *if you make sure you never exceed the critical temperature when they become hard and dry*. This is the mechanism that makes sous vide so successful. Whether a slow cooker is suited to the task remains to be seen. The long stewing method slow cookers are so famous for is quite different.

Comment: @Stephie - The issue I'm raising is not so much whether you can get an acceptable or favorable result, but whether that method is best suited for the characteristics of the cut.  If I get an acceptable result for a pork tenderloin, which is 5 to 10 times more expensive than a cheaper cut that will give me an also acceptable result, then why am I using that particular cut?